Cloning specific Git repo from inside WSL2 fails
I recently set up Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Noble Numbat inside of Windows Subsystem for Linux version 2 on a system running Windows 10 22H2 on a secure enterprise network (with proxies and firewalls). It has been working really well and I seem to have full access to the network with ping, DNS, HTTP(S) and SSH. For example, I can install software using APT just fine. However, I am facing one major issue: I can clone some, but not other Git repositories. I have to clone repositories over SSH using key-based authentication, and when doing so for the ones I can't I get the following error message after minutes of waiting:
Cloning into 'Foo'...
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

Accessing the git server using ssh -T works just fine, as do nslookup'ing its hostname, pinging it and getting web pages from it using curl. I can clone some other repos from the Git server just fine.
I have tried all the commonly suggested fixes, but none seem to work. Here is a list of things I have tried and that failed:

Setting IPQoS to throughput and setting a ServerAliveInterval in ~/.ssh/config like this:
Host *
   ServerAliveInterval 600
   IPQoS throughput


Setting networkingMode=mirrored in /etc/wsl.conf and restarting the distribution (using the 8 second rule) like so:
[wsl2]
networkingMode=mirrored


Increasing Git's http.postBuffer setting to 1048576000 (the repos are rather big)
Increasing the distro's MTU from 1500 to 9000 bytes
Checking and disabling the host system's configured firewalls

After applying any of these ideas I still get exactly the same error. Running Git with environment variable GIT_SSH_COMMAND set to ssh -vvv indicates the connection is setup and the user (me) is authenticated successfully, but just ends in almost the same notification that the remote end hung up unexpectedly.
On the same machine I can clone the problematic repositories through SSH in both native Windows, MSYS2 and virtual machines running in VMWare Workstation Player.
What could be going wrong here? How would I find out? I am really perplexed ...
Thank you in advance for your input!

As you said,

the repos are rather big

so it's likely that the clone is just timing out. I'm not familiar with the WSL specifics, but http.postBuffer will have zero effect on an SSH session, and changing the MTU to a jumbo frame will only work if all nodes in your route to whatever server are also at that setting (otherwise you'll just get bumped back down to 1500 or whatever, along with a lot of extra fragmentation).
Instead, consider a partial clone. The details here will likely depend on your aims:

If you are cloning this for regular development work, then a "blobless" clone would be best; Git will fetch all reachable commits and trees, and then fetch blobs as necessary. Blobless clones look like git clone --filter=blob:none <url>.
If you are cloning this for a build process (etc) where you need full history but will be discarding the repo after you're done, then a "treeless" clone could work well; Git will fetch all the reachable commits, and then fetch trees and blobs as necessary. Treeless clones look like git clone --filter=tree:0 <url>.
If you are cloning this for a build process (etc) where you only need the latest version and will be discarding the repo after you're done, then a classic "shallow" clone will fetch the latest version of the repo and nothing else. Shallow clones look like git clone --depth=n <url> (where n is the number of commits to fetch - in practice most people just need 1).

GitHub has an excellent blog post on partial clones, which I recommend as further reading.

Thanks for your quick, detailed and helpful reply! While our Tuleap Git server does not support filters for blobless/treeless I can indeed clone the repo using --depth=1, but I discovered that more fundamentally I can clone in WSL2 when using --no-tags. I should mention that the Git clients outside of WSL2 with which I clone are also relatively old (v2.21) while the Git in WSL2 is pretty recent (2.43). Can there be a problem with the tags in recent versions of Git?

I tried installing Git v2.45 as the native Windows Git, overriding version 2.21 from which I could clone the repo with tags. But I can still clone the repo with tags in 2.45 there, in contrast to version 2.42 on WSL2
